# Web Scraping: Hover info from charts on a web page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, mousehover

I am trying to scrape information in the hover info as you can see in the image, the hover info is dynamic i.e. the info '4.7K','6%', would change as the mouse is hovered on different bars. I'm using selenium for this task.  [image: This the link for the image : https://www.semrush.com/analytics/overview/?searchType=subdomain&q=https%3A%2F%2Fcreditcards.chase.com%2F]

Comment: Is there any code you've tried and got some output ? Are you able to hover onto the elements ?

Comment: I tried to hover but somehow it just hovers on second and 4th bar only and I want it for all of them in a ordered fashion used this code;                                                 
 from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
a = ActionChains(driver)
m = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="domain-overview-app"]/div/div/div[4]/div[5]/section/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div')  
a.move_to_element(m).perform()

Comment: So you are looking assistance with hover as well. Is it possible to share page url ?

Comment: https://www.semrush.com/analytics/overview/?searchType=subdomain&q=https%3A%2F%2Fcreditcards.chase.com%2F

Comment: I want to get just thosetext elements in hover

Comment: It needs creds to login.. I do not have creds to login. also your xpath look brittle, please use relative xpath

Comment: you can create your own trial account

Comment: Instead you should provide HTML in text format here so that folks here can give you more optimize solution.

Comment: @cruisepandey can you connect telegram:@mishra_31, linkedin : https://www.linkedin.com/in/abhishek-mishra-b14216180/